# How to manually number Chapter number when using \input?

Tags: numbering, chapters, input

I am writing my Thesis using the memoir class. To keep my main .tex file fairly short I use the `\input` command to compile the chapters. This also helps when I only want to send a chapter on to my supervisor for reviewing as I can `%` out the `\input` of the chapter I don't want to compile. My issue is though that when, for example, only send on one chapter it will automatically be renumbered Chapter 1 even though it could be Chapter 4 in context of all the other chapter.

Good time for some background info. My supervisor does not use LaTeX so I can't just send him the TeX files. I send a pdf document which is why the problem arises. It's a small issue but can lead to some confusion as to what chapter I'm sending.

I don't know if I can do a MWE that would be helpful but I hope I have described my issue enough. What I ideally want is some small bit of code that I can use to temporally renumber the Chapters when only compiling some of them?

Comment: Use `\include` instead of `\input` and compile the file. After that in the main file add in the preamble `\includeonly{chapter1}` (where `chapter1.tex` is the chapter you want to include) and compile again.

Comment: Another workaround is putting the chapter headers in the main file, outside the `\input`. Just to be clearer, I mean so that your main file would read `\chapter{Introduction} \input{chapter1-contents.tex} \chapter{State of the Art} \input{chapter2-contents.tex} ...`

Comment: This usage is exactly why latex has `\include` and `\includeonly` not only will that give the correct number it will allow \ref to things in the omitted chapters, something that will not work if you simply comment them out and use `\input`

Comment: @karlkoeller if you wish to add your comment as an answer I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX provides the commands `\include` and `\includeonly` for this purpose.

First of all, replace all your `\input` commands with `\include` in your main file. Then, supposing that `chapter4.tex` is the chapter you want to print, add this line in your main file preamble.

```
%\includeonly{chapter4}
```

Now compile your file and, if any, your bibliography, your index, etc.

At this point, uncomment the above line in your main file and recompile.

You will notice that you get only `chapter4.tex` printed, with all correct references, citations, etc.

For further reading, I suggest [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/27635)